# How to do a TFS Gated check in for TypeScript?

Tags: angular, typescript, tfs

We will be starting an Angular 4 project soon using TypeScript, Visual Studio Code, and Team Foundation Server for the source control/CI.  We want to do a gated check in where the build server ensures that the TypeScript passes TSLint before it is able to be checked in.  How can this be done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I run TSLint (and all other linters) via Gulp.  So long as Gulp throws an error, it will cause the TFS Build to fail, which will cause the gated checkin to fail.